# Excel query regarding column population

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I had a query in excel. I do not know how to describe it correctly so i will give you an example. I have a data set like.

```
Andy A
Andy B 
Andy C
Rob A
Rob C
```

and so on. now when i need to filter, currently i need to select all the Andys or robs one by one. instead of that i want a another column having entry as Andy for all the andys and hence while filtering instead selecting all the andys i can do my job by selecting only andy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could accomplish this.

1. If the number of names is small, you could do as you suggest, and create a column for each name. It would look like this:

   ```
   Name  Category  Andy   Rob
   Andy  A         yes    no
   Andy  B         yes    no
   Andy  C         yes    no
   Rob   A         no     yes
   Rob   C         no     yes
   ```

   This is accomplished by using this formula in C2 (and copy/pasting through the rest of the table):

   ```
   =IF($A2=C$1,"yes","no")
   ```
2. If your list of names is long, then you'd have lots of extra columns, which may not be desirable. You can simply use a text filter: click the filter dropdown, choose Text Filter -> Equals -> type Andy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Text Autofilter` together with `Begins With`.

> **Create a Custom Filter**
>
> Some of the AutoFilter options in the drop down lists end with three
>   dots, such as Begins With...
>
> [image]
>
> These filters, as well as the Custom Filter option, open the Custom
>   AutoFilter window. In there, you can enter one or two criteria, to
>   create a customized filter.
>
> To filter for one criterion:
>
> 1. From the first dropdown list, select an option, such as "begins with".
> 2. In the text box, type a value, then Click OK.
>
> In the screen shot below, the Custom Filter will find records where
>   the customer name begins with "M".
>
> [image]

Source [Excel Filters: AutoFilter Basics](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html)